# Cannot group table values by ID

Tags: php, mysql

Hey there guys/girls I have an issue I'm currently trying to work through being a novice to MYSQL / PHP. Currently I'm using Bootstrap accordion collapsible components to display HTML tables (That are reports). Here is my current table:
[Current Table in MYSQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OaKyN.png).

So as you can see the `reports` row contains some HTML information which are tables. I wanted to take the information and display it on a webpage assuming that *every row was a different report*. So I was able to do so with writing this:

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
        <?php   
    require('db.php');
$i = 0;
$sql = "SELECT `report` FROM `automation-reports`;";
$query = mysqli_query($connection,  $sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    foreach($row as $key => $value)
    {


        ?>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="heading<?php echo $i ?>">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse<?php echo $i ?>" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse<?php echo $i ?>">
          Report #1: 8/6/2018
        </button>
      </h5>
    </div>

    <div id="collapse<?php echo $i ?>" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading<?php echo $i ?>" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div style="text-align: center;" class="card-body">
                <h3 style="float: left;"> Rating-Pull: </h3>
                    <?php 
                            $i++;
                            echo $key;
        echo "$value";
        ?>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<?php
    }
}
?>
</div>
```

Which is great because it does what I *thought* I wanted it to do , which is this:
[Display Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3D57.png)

What's not so great is now I realize that multiple reports are going to be in one accordion "folder" which is where the `reportid` row comes into play. So lets say I run my program and two (different) reports run on it but I want it in the say "folder" on the webpage. Both of these get labeled with a `reportid` of `1`.

So what I want to do is loop through `reports` and then if they have the same ID group them together in that folder and iterate through the whole table like that. So that's the part where I have attempted to do so with a nested loop and `SELECT 'report' FROM 'automation-reports' WHERE 'reportid' = '$i' ;` and I just ended up getting the first element. Could somebody give me a hand with this and a *good* explanation so I can understand and learn what's happening?

Thank you!

EDIT:
Maybe a  visual would be better?
[VISUAL](https://prnt.sc/kfsbgu)

Comment: GROUP the data by report id in your query, and then implement a “control break” (this is a pretty standard programming principle, so you should be able to research whatever else info you need besides what https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_break already explains.)

Comment: `reportid` isn't included in my original query, it just queries the `reports` row, it has no association with the other row right now. Are you saying create another query on top of my original one to do so?

Comment: No, I am saying select all the data you need directly in your original query.

Comment: I have tried a bunch of different ways including using GROUP_CONCAT and GROUPBY with no luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `GROUP BY` and `GROUP_CONCAT` are what you are looking for.

```
SELECT `reportid`, GROUP_CONCAT(`report` SEPARATOR '') as report
FROM `automation-reports`
GROUP BY `reportid`
```

shoud do the job.

Comment: Is the value correct ?
I forgot you use the key afterwards. I am editing my answer to fit your code.

Comment: The values ... look correct kinda, I can't tell because of how the code displays. It was the same result with the edited code.

Comment: Sorry to ask it again, but did you test with the 'as report' I have added to the query ?
The ugly GROUP_CONCAT shoudn't be displayed any more.

Comment: Yes! I added your bit of code and I got that ugly output where it put the accordion folders inside each other.

Comment: Turns out this was correct all along. The real issue is that `GROUP_CONCAT` trims your string for anything over 1024 Characters. Once I set that to a higher limit I was fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM `automation-reports`
GROUP BY `reportid`
```

will give you one row for each id ie.

1. id 1,
2. id 2,
3. id 3

Or do you want to display each row like so?

1. id 1, id 1,
2. id 2,
3. id 3, id 3,
4. id 4

if so here is a possible example of combining the reports in a loop first

```
$sql = "SELECT reportid, GROUP_CONCAT(report SEPARATOR ',') as reports FROM `automation-reports` GROUP BY `reportid`;";



while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {

  echo "<div id='{$row['reportid']}'>";

  echo $row['reports'];

  echo "</div>";

}
```

I know this isn't the HTML you're after but you should be able to place your HTML in this code

Comment: I want to group by `reportid`. So if `reportid` = 1 then grab `report` equivalent(s) and display them. So the second one.

Comment: I'm not sure where you're pulling 'name' and 'created_at' from? Maybe you misunderstood my question or I didn't explain it correctly. In my database I have three values and two of those have `reportid` = 1. I want to grab both of the ones with the same `reportid` and grab the associated `report` with it, so it would display two of them. The 'lonely' one with the ID of 0, would just display by itself BUT if there was another 'group' display those together as well.

Comment: Sorry, name and created at where just an example of the columns you might want to display, sorry for the assumption. But that should do what you want, just not literally haha

Comment: I assume ` $reports[$row['id']] = $row;` 'id' is assumed as well? Or are you actually going by my `ID` row in the database?

Comment: Hmm, my code is as follows: [code](http://prntscr.com/kfrrwg) and I get `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\FI-ReportsSite\dashboard.php on line 46`

Comment: $row['id'] would be the id on the table row, so you wouldnt have to use $i

Comment: This returns me 4 accordion "folders" with `Warning: Illegal string offset 'report' in C:\xampp\htdocs\FI-ReportsSite\dashboard.php on line 67
1` inside each

Comment: There's three rows in the database, two of which have the same ID. This is going to change once the database grows though, so we could have 100 items and 80 of them are grouped together by their ID. For this example we have three rows though and  two have the same ID. So I would need two folders, one to display the one with the same ID's and one to display the one by itself.

Comment: Your edited code didn't work for me either unfortunately. I've been at this for a couple hours now and still no luck either.